# How can I generate URLs using Ajax based on webpage content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch, dynamically-generated

I am trying to build toggle buttons that will be on each product page of an e-commerce website. The buttons will toggle back and forth between the pages associated with "Men's" and "Women's" version of each product.

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('womens') > -1 ) {
        $('a.gender-toggle-women').attr("href", $(location).attr('href'));
        $('a.gender-toggle-men').attr("href", $(location).attr('href').replace('womens','mens'));
    }
   else {
  $('a.gender-toggle-men').attr("href", $(location).attr('href'));
  $('a.gender-toggle-women').attr("href", $(location).attr('href').replace('mens','womens'));
   }
});
```

I wanted to use a script like the one above to redirect users to a new page when they click the toggle buttons, but it doesn't work because the url paths are slightly different.

Example:

/shop/womens-running-shoe-sku1?variationId=333

vs

/shop/mens-running-shoe-sku2?variationId=444

So, instead I'd like to use Ajax (or Fetch?) to generate urls based on the product titles listed on the product pages.

If I do this

```
var product = $("h1.product-content-info-name.product-info-js").attr("data-catentry-name-dl");

var prodTransform = product.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase().replace(/'/g, '');
```

and transform "Men's Running Shoe" to "mens-running-shoe" to make it match the format of the page url, can I use Ajax (or Fetch?) to return the entire associated url or html file path?

I know this may seem like a weird roundabout way to do this, but I am creating this toggle through an a/b testing platform, so I don't have direct access to the back-end of the website and I have to do everything client side. I also don't want to waste time creating a different version of the a/b test for each of the product pages and have to manually type out the urls for each.

I am also pretty new to development and coding in general, and I've been learning primarily through trial and error. So if it seems like I'm missing something rather obvious, please let me know.

I've been searching everywhere for resources to help me do what I am trying to do but I haven't been able to find anything super useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, but you can't use Fetch to get the URL. Fetch is used to get a specific page so if you don't have a specific page you can't get the URL out of it. Unless you just want to fetch `/shop/mens-running-shoe` URL. If this is the case then you can do that and use $(html) with the response from an Ajax request and you can use jQuery to traverse that HTML and get the full URL if it's on the link.

Comment: @jcubic Yes I just want to fetch the page! I'll try to do what you've suggested. Also, for reference, there's an example of what I'm trying to recreate here: https://www.on-running.com/en-us/products/cloudswift-41/mens/all-black-shoes-41.98462

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @jcubic I want to create a toggle like the one in the link I sent. But I can't figure out how to generate the url on click. The site I linked uses Apollo Link's CreateHTTPLink, but I can't do that because I need a client-side solution

Comment: But where this URL come from?